# Extending the Enumerable class in c#?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, static-classes

I have situation to extend the Enumerable class in c# to add the new Range method that accepts long parameters. I cannot define the method like this

```
public static IEnumerable<long> Range(this Enumerable source, long start, long length)
{
    for (long i = start; i < length; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Since extension methods are accesible only through its objects. And it gives me an error

> 'System.Linq.Enumerable': static types
>   cannot be used as parameters

Can someonce clarify me how to do this

Note: I know we can easily solve this without extension methods, but i needed this Enumrable class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You (like me) are looking for static extension methods:

http://madprops.org/blog/static-extension-methods/

It's not possible in C#. The closest alternative is to define another static class with a similar name (LongEnumerable?) and add your static method to that.

Answer (score 5):

Extension methods can only be called on *instances* of a type, and since `Enumerable` is a static type there will never be any instances of it, which means that you can't extend it.

It makes no sense to have your `Range` method as an extension on `IEnumerable<T>` either. Your method just generates a sequence of `long` values, it doesn't need to extend any particular instance.

Use a standard static utility method instead:

```
var example = EnumerableUtils.Range(0, long.MaxValue).Where(x => (x % 2) == 0);

// ...

public static class EnumerableUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<long> Range(long start, long count)
    {
        for (long i = start; i < start + count; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to extend System.Linq.Enumerable?
This class uses Extension methods to extend OTHER types that implement IEnumerable.

The result would be, that you'd call:

```
Enumerable.Range(long, long);
```

You'd rather extend the long class directly:

```
public static IEnumerable<long> Range(this long source, long length)
{
    for (long i = source; i < length; i++)
    {
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

This way you can start with

```
foreach (long item in 10.Range(20)) { }
```

Comment: `Enumerable` is a static utility class. For the same reason they did not extent `int`, a new class like `LongEnumerableTools` is the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend the `Enumerable` class, since you don't have an `Enumerable` instance - it's a `static` class. Extension methods only work on instances, they never work on the static class itself.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to create your own utility class for that; you can'd add static methods via extension methods.